# Highcharts : show time with 30 second interval

Tags: jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I have a highchart that updates every second. and the data in x-axis is also second wise like 
10:30:00  10:30:01   10:30:02 .....

But i need to display only 10:30:00 10:30:30  10:31:00 , but plot all points.
That is show x-axis with the interval of 30 seconds but plot all points.

I have given my graph code. **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bf82813k/10/).**

Here It will not update second wise because i have commented the code that calls data from my aspx page.

```
return "{" + string.Join(",", listData) + "}";
```

This is how i send data from my aspx page. and looks like 
 { "12:30:10": 100, "12:30:11": 200, "12:30:12": 40, "12:30:13": 40, "12:30:14": 50, "12:30:15": 0, "12:30:16": 0, "12:30:17": 0 }

Can anyone help me doing this?

Comment: Better is remove categores, use datetime type and set tickInterval. Data (which you get dynamically) should be transform to timestamp and added to chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `tickInterval` option to x axis:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: c,                     
    tickInterval:30
}
```

See updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bf82813k/11/) here.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. But it shows only one point when data is updating.And only that one point is updating 30 seconds

Comment: I had to make it 3 instead of 30. I have no idea why is it so

Comment: Think you need to use high stock charts.
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: How would highstock give any advantage over highcharts in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to this will be to skip the categories, and use a datetime x axis type.

You can then set the tickinterval to the number of miliseconds you want (ie, for 30 seconds, it would 30,000)

The reason that you had to set the tickinterval to a value that didn't make sense is that you are using categories, so a tickInterval of 30 means to only show a tick every 30 categories...

something like this:

```
$.each(data, function (i, e) {
  var ddate = new Date(i);
  var dtime = ddate.getTime();
  var dpoint = [dtime, parseInt(e)];
  seriesData.push(dpoint);
});
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/p109zbrd/